# Start a feature branch in another feature branch

Tags: git, git-branch, git-flow, git-config

I created (`git flow feature start branch1`) and published (`git flow feature publish branch1`) a git flow feature branch based on `develop`. After them, I have this marked as a `Pull Request`, that another developer look at the changes in this branch. But now I want to work further, so I create a new feature branch (`git flow feature start branch2`) based on `branch1` where is waiting for `Pull Request`. But after creating `branch2`, there are only the files, where in `branch1` are ignored (all files, where matched with the condition in `.gitignore`).

When I checked out `branch1`, I see the whole dictionary with all files, but why are in the new created feature branch (`branch2`) not all files? So I can't work further.

## I found the problem, but not the solution:

In `.git/config` file, there is written, that the **base** from my `branch2` the `develop` branch is, and not `branch1`:

```
[gitflow "branch.feature/branch1"]
        base = develop
[branch "feature/branch1"]
        remote = origin
        merge = refs/heads/feature/branch1
[gitflow "branch.feature/branch2"]
        base = develop
```

With following command I can move all files from `branch1` in `branch2`, but the *base* in the `.git/config`-file changed not to `branch1`...:

```
git rebase --onto feature/branch1 develop feature/branch2
```

<sub>Building with this template: `git rebase --onto newBase oldBase feature/branch`</sub>

How can I change the *base-branch* from my `branch2`? Simply by changing *base-branch* from `branch2` to `branch1` in `.git/config`?

Answer (score 1):

You could change the `base` in your `.git/config` but you should not.

The `base` for `branch2` is also `develop` since this is the branch you want to merge to later (after `branch1` is already merged).

This is also reflected in `git flow feature start branch2`, which does not start where you currently are but always from `develop`. That's the whole idea of [git-flow](https://nvie.com/posts/a-successful-git-branching-model/).

Don't worry about the `.git/config` now unless you want to do something that your question doesn't specifically express.

Merge the PR for `branch1` and then create the PR for `branch2` and everything will work normally.